# Java: Peculiar division behviour

Tags: java, math, behavior

I would expect `System.out.println(13 / 31)` to print `0.419354838709677`.

It prints `0.0`. Why?

Comment: I don't believe you that the code you've posted prints `0.0`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis try it. It does. If it does not, post what you get.

Comment: It definitely does not return `0.0`. `0`, sure, but not `0.0`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis further research on my part shows that you were right. My code was printing the return value of a method which returned a `double`.

Comment: `println` has many overloaded flavors.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know. How is that relevant?

Comment: The value of `13/31` is an `int`, so the `println(int)` method got invoked and could not have printed a floating point value. You must have invoked the overloaded method which takes a `float` or `double`. I'm explaining my reasoning.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis there was never a call to `println(int)`, only `println(double)`.

Comment: Right, so you would never have gotten the output you showed us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are dividing an int with an int therefore the result will be an int

try

```
System.out.println(13.0 / 31)
```

or

```
System.out.println((float)13 / 31)
```